# Grails Dynamic Finder .findAllById(id) vs .findById(id) with new object in same transaction

Tags: grails, dynamic, transactions, grails-orm, dynamic-finders

I'm experiencing strange behaviour between

- .findAllById(id)
- .findById(id)

I'm creating a new domain class and then later in the same transaction I'm looking up that same object with a dynamic finder. When using .findAllById(newObjectId) it finds the newly created object but .findById(newObjectId) does not. It's appears .findById() is not searching through uncommitted objects in the transaction?

We recently configured a second datasource which seems to work fine but in doing so we began to experience this behaviour.

On the grails documents I found "The findAll method supports the 2nd level cache".

Does this mean dynamic finder .find doesn't support 2nd level cache?

Comment: Uncommitted objects and the second-level cache are completely unrelated

Comment: Are you using MongoDB?

Comment: Nope not using MongoDB.